# Issue when trying to retrieve data from a referenced table using Hibernate.

Tags: java, hibernate

Error:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException  SEVERE: could
>   not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed

Code:

```
System.out.println(resultStudent.getStudentAddress().getCity());
```

Here the `getAddress()` returns an `Address` object and i am trying to get the city of the student using `getCity()` of `Address` class.  Why do I get the above error?

Just getting the Address object doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate **loads the relationships lazily**. So when you are navigating the relationship you need to either have the hibernate session open or fetch the data eagerly. Read the below articles

1. [Understanding Lazy Fetching](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t20533.html)
2. [Fetch strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching)